# Не работает код после обновления Swift до 4.2

Tags: swift

Есть код, до обновления работал, а теперь перестал,
как его пофиксить, чтобы компилировался?

```
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: AnyObject?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>?) {
        if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {
            if webView?.estimatedProgress == 1.0
            {
                if ((webView?.url?.absoluteURL.absoluteString.range(of: "access_token")) != nil) &&  webView?.url?.host == "oauth.vk.com" {
                    webView?.isHidden = true

                    let parameters = webView?.url?.absoluteURL.absoluteString.components(separatedBy: "#")[1]

                    let parameters_token = parameters?.components(separatedBy: "&")[0]

                    VK_Access_Token = parameters?.substring(with: (parameters_token?.characters.startIndex.advance(13, for: parameters_token!))!..<(parameters_token?.characters.endIndex)!)

                    UserDefaults.standard.set(VK_Access_Token, forKey: "VK_Access_Token")

                    webView?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress")

                    let mainPage = MainController()
                    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage)
                    PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Пишет Method does not override any method from its superclass

Answer (score 0):

```
Вот изменненый метод

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    // code ....
}
```